# Can't get my sidebar on the right-hand side

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm an amateur with CSS and have tried using some guides to get myself so far. I've set up a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/defaye/X9t7M/1/ for anyone who may know what I'm doing wrong? I can't get the sidebar on the right-hand side as a right-most column of the main content.

CSS structure

```
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 950px;
  max-width: 1110px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
  float: left;
  height: 354px;
  width: 100%;
}

#navigation {
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

#container {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

#main {
  margin-right: 200px;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: -300px;
  float: left;
}

#footer {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}
```

HTML structure

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="navigation"></div>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="main"></div>
      <div id="sidebar"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X9t7M/3/) how it works.  Here is [your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X9t7M/5/)

```
#main, #sidebar {
    float: left;
}

#main {
    width: 70%;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your first edit pointed me in the right direction too. Thanks for also presenting it in an updated fiddle.